# How to load a method without event?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute a function after the page load, instead of waiting for an event, in JS. However, I need this function to work with the `this` keyword. It works perfectly fine with the event, but if I try to load it alone, it displays an error in the console.

```js
function doSomething() {
    console.log(this.checked);
}
var myCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for (let i = 0; i < myCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    myCheckboxes[i].doSomething(); // doesn't work after loading
    myCheckboxes[i].addEventListener("change", doSomething); // works on event
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `myCheckboxes[i].doSomething(); // doesn't work after loading` - of course it doesn't - `doSomething` is not a property of `myCheckboxes[i]` in the first place.

Comment: You can use `doSomething.call(myCheckboxes[i]);`

Comment: Checkboxes don’t have a `doDomething` property. This seems like an XY problem—what’s wrong with the conventional approach?

Comment: Thank you very much @Pointy, I never met the call() function before